# cabal: installing documentation under hsenv

Tags: cabal, cabal-install, haddock, hsenv

I have a hsenv sandbox for a project, and I can't get cabal install to install the documentation for the libraries. The following:

```
cabal install --enable-documentation $package
```

installs the package, but without generating any haddock docs (only LICENSE and such are copied to the docs directory). The build log contains only:

```
install-outcome: InstallOk
docs-outcome: Ok
tests-outcome: NotTried
```

I can't get any useful information out of cabal install, even with verbose=3. Outside of hsenv, everything works just fine. Any ideas on how to fix, or at least debug this?